# How to override on click-listener for button in webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am working in application which contains Web-View. Until here every thing works fine for me,
But here is my problem, i have an button in Web-View, which i need to invoke and start a new activity.

Below is the java-Script code, how to invoke onclik to the button in andorid.

```
<a id="tradeLink" href="/Home.mvc/ Hello android " >
    <button id="btnTrade" type="button" class="btn">Trade</button></a>
```

Here is the screenshot attached for further reference:

[image]

How to get button click listener on click of trade?

Answer (score 1):

You need [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) 
For example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    String html = "<html><head></head><body>" +
            "<button onclick=\"jsinterface.dosomething()\">Try it</button>" +
            "</body></html>";
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "jsinterface");
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
    ...
}

class JSInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface        // Don't forget this line
    public void dosomething() { // Must be public
        // Start your new activity here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called Bridging. You've to create an interface which connects the javascript to the real device.

Here's an example:

http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2012/03/16/android-development-javascript-bridge-example-fully-explained/

[image]